# Offline SDK and ADT installation

Tags: android, installation

I am trying to install on a VM that is offline.  I have downloaded eclipse.  I have downloaded the android sdk and pointed to it in eclipse.  I still cannot see any target platforms in order to create an android project.  What am i missing?  I need to set this up without using the android sdk/avd manager to download the platforms.  Can anyone help me?  I have been trying to figure this out for 3 days.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry But I have No time to answer

This helped me to do it

http://qdevarena.blogspot.com/2010/05/download-android-sdk-standalone-for.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to download them outside of the SDK/AVD manager.  If your VM doesn't have network connectivity, your best bet is probably to download the SDKs you are interested in (from a different system) and manually copy over the files.  The SDKs will reside in the "platforms" directory underneath the SDK root.  If you download the Google API add-ons, those files will reside in the "add-ons" subdirectory.

Comment: This worked for me, for android-2.1_r01-windows, and google_apis-7_r01.

Thanks